# How do I disable Google voice command?

Tags: lg

Since the new Google update, my beloved and must have to get through the eight hours at work head phones have turned into my worst nightmare. Voice pops up and decides it's a good time to turn the volume up full blast while I'm listening to music. I really don't want permanent hearing  Ioss. If I cough, it goes mute. I tried to disable through the settings and it won't stay. It also takes the liberty to change the ring from vibrate to silent. This is the worst update ever! Please help...my breaks at work really suck now. How can I turn this crap off?? I have a droid LG 10.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Say "OK Google", hit the Menu Button, goto Settings, drill down to here and set as shown in the Screenshot.]

This ensures that the correct APP is opened and sets it to work only when the APP is running, instead of in the background.